how to tell if a tab is open in a Blazor Server Side solution?
I am working on a Blazor chat application (.NET 8) that uses SignalR to receive messages in real-time. When a new message arrives and the user has the relevant chat open, the message is automatically added to the chat window:
            if (OpenedChat is not null && recieverId == MyId && senderId == OpenedChat.User.Id)
            {
                var newMessage = new TalkChatMessage
                    {
                        SenderId = senderId,
                        ReceiverId = MyId,
                        Content = message,
                        Timestamp = DateTime.Now
                    };
                messages.Add(newMessage);
                InvokeAsync(async () =>
                {
                    await ChatService.ReadMessage(MsgId);
                    StateHasChanged();
                    await ScrollToBottom();
                });
            }

However, I would like to trigger a notification sound when a message arrives but the user is not currently on the chat's tab in the browser (the chat is oppened in one tab but the user is currently on reddit's tab). I've read that this can be done by checking the tab's visibility state, but I'm not sure how to integrate this with my existing SignalR setup.
I want to add a check to determine if the tab is inactive, and if so, trigger a notification sound like this:
                    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("playNotificationSound");


How are you rendering your tabs?

@GHDevOps the tab i meant was the browser's tab, not one built in the solution using HTML/CSS, i just noticed that the way i wrote was misleading, sorry i will edit it

Keep in mind you can only have one active tab and browser window at a given time. If a tab is inactive for a certain amount of time, your browser will stop most of your resources until that tab is active again, including SignalR.

This is evil.  Don't do this, even if you can.
